# "The file 'file.odt' is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened." when change picture using OpenTBS

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

1. I'm testing the OpenTBS library to use it to generate a document in my project. I created a .odt file in LibreOffice with the image as stated in the documentation and other posts on StackOverflow. However, when I change the image, after saving the file and trying to open it, I get an error:
   "The file 'file.odt' is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened. LibreOffice can try to repair the file.
   The corruption could be the result of document manipulation or of structural document damage due to data transmission."

[image: PrintScreen from LibreOffice]

In libreOffice, it adds in the description what is in the picture above. I will add that I've already tried various options: [onshow.], OPENTBS_CHANGE_PICTURE on the PHP side, everything gives a similar result.

[image: Error opening]

When LibreOffice repairs the file, everything is as it should be in the document, i.e. the image is replaced, but I would not like the file to be repaired.

2. Taking this opportunity, I would like to ask if there is a possibility to override "Image Control" in the same way as an image. I would like the user to be able to download the document without the image, then the "Image control" form will appear in the place of the image, if you click it, it will select the image itself. Can I use "Image Control" in the template and on the application side replace it with an image if I want.

Comment: For changing the picture of an Image Control, you cannot use `ope=changepic` parameter, but you can directly use  the commend `OPENTBS_REPLACEFILE` in order to replace the underlying image file in the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on the forum: https://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php?thr=3506
Just add exit(); or die(); after the show() function.